# Is there a new schema location for websphere ibm-web-bnd.xml?

Tags: java, xml, websphere

This used to work fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">   
    <virtual-host name="default_host" />
</web-bnd>
```

And at deploy-time it still does but Eclipse's validator keeps show annoying "errors" because http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee does not point to a valid site anymore (redirects to some search site),when trying to download the schemas.

I know that probably I'll just have to turn off validation for these files, but let me try asking first:

- Is there a new home for those schemas?
- Or somewhere to alert IBM that they are failing miserably on that regard...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install WebSphere Developer Tools via Eclipse Marketplace. It will add required schema to the XML Catalog in the Eclipse. You can check if you have them via `Preferences > XML > XML catalog`. These schemas are in one of the jars from plugin (the exact filename can be different depending on tools version)

```
Location: schemas\ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd in jar file C:\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.jee.was.descriptors.schemas_1.1.100.v20141119_2034.jar.
```

Comment: Is there no other way?  What if I'm not using eclipse?

Comment: Then you can download it, install the WDT, extract the file and then remove Eclipse. I don't know the other location, and looking for it will take longer time than this solution.

Answer (score 2):

For Websphere Application Server:

You can find all the schemas here...

**WAS_INSTALL_ROOT/properties/schemas**